# Сериализация double в JSON

Tags: c#, json, округление

У класса есть свойство типа `double`, как задать, чтобы оно сериализовалось с конкретным количеством знаков после запятой?

Comment: Какую библиотеку Вы используте?

Comment: А округлить перед сериализацией вручную не вариант?

Answer (score 3):

Именно при сериализации вряд ли. Можно самому числу ограничить количество знаков после запятой используя [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) или перевести в строку

```
.ToString("#.##");
```